# CheckToken() error when TinyMCE init

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, tinymce, security-token, jsession

I have a form, which add some data to DataBase.

```
<form>
 <input type="text" name="mydata" />
 <textarea name="mytext"></textarea>
 <?php echo JHtml::_( 'form.token' );?>
 <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Clicking Submit, I send data to outside script, which insert data to DB. I'm checking session token (to prevent csrf attack) and then make script actions. To do this, I use Joomla JSession method `checkToken()`.

```
<?php
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define( 'JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/../..' ));

require_once ( JPATH_BASE. '/includes/defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE. '/includes/framework.php' );

$mainframe = JFactory::getApplication('site');
$mainframe->initialise();

$session = JFactory::getSession();
$session->checkToken() or die('Access denied');
```

That's all good, when script look like above.

But when I init TinyMCE plugin for textarea, using [tiny.cloud](http://tiny.cloud) docs, I have "Access Denied" response from script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found answer. The problem, that TinyMCE have own submit function and submit form 
independently of my ajax.
Add

```
setup: function(editor){
 editor.on('submit', function(){
  return false;
 });
}
```

to tinymce init config and `tinymce.triggerSave()` before Ajax function, and it will be all good.

Comment: Please accept your answer so that this page is deemed resolved by the system and it stops getting "bumped".

Comment: you have been on this site in the last couple of weeks.  Please take a second to award your answer the green tick.